# What is your preferred order of elements in the body of program code? Why?

Tags: c#, java

Of course at the top of a .java or .cs file are the package/namespace declaration followed by import/using statement.

But what riles me is where should I put the variable declaration? At the top or at the bottom?

This is how I prefer;

```
package/namespace declaration
import/using declaration of microsoft's/java namespaces
import/using declaration of standard 3rd party namespaces
import/using declaration of my personal namespaces

constructors
private methods, each preceded by any private variable that was first used.
protected methods, each preceded by any private variable that was first used.
public methods, each preceded by any private variable that was first used.

inner/nested classes and enums

private anon classes assignment
protected variables/anon classes assignment
public variables/assigned anon classes assignment
```

But I realise many people like to put all the variables right at the top after the     package/namespace and import/using declarations. That is troublesome because sometimes the number of variables and assigned anon classed gets too many, and that obscures the visibility of the constructors - the first lines I need to be visible are the constructors because they tell me the signature of instantiation.

And then for anon classes that are immediately assigned to a variable - I consider them part of the "structure of variables", so I group them variables.

I systematize the placement of my code elements to enable me to easily locate them.

Comment: Sorry please reread the question. There was a problem with my chrome browser which cut off half my question.

Comment: It's an interesting thought.  Since the properties and private members of a class are usually the least interesting part of the class I do normally skip right over them to find the issues in my methods that need fixing or extending.  It makes a bit of sense to push them to the bottom.  I may have to give it a try and see if I grow to like it or not.

Answer (score 1):

The Java standard says to order your declarations from private to public. I find that really helps me a lot. I'm not sure why, but reading code bottom up works really well for me. So I've adopted that over to C# (my main language) where I order a class as

```
using statements
namespace
private static fields
private static methods/properties
public static methods/properties
private fields
private methods/properties
protected methods/properties
public methods/properties
```

I don't give constructors their own section like most people do, except that they are the first entry of their category (so public constructors come just after protected methods, for example). I almost never use internally scoped things, except for entire classes.

I never use regions, and I never use public fields (always properties)

Answer (score 1):

I tend to order things in the same order I would use them. Namespace, followed by `using` declarations, followed by constructors, then nested classes, then parameters, public methods, and finally private methods. Basically, it's in a readable order of what someone new to my code should read in order to get a breadth-first idea of what the class does. It's also in order of how they will be used; first you need to know the namespace, then how to construct, then how to configure, then how to use.

In addition to that, private member variables are always next to wherever they are used. If I have a private helper method I try to put it next to the corresponding public method and clump them in a `#region`. But typically any private members would go near the bottom, because I feel someone using the class would need to read them less often than the public members.

I think it also depends on whether you're writing code that others will read vs. writing code that only you are maintaining. When it's the latter, I tend to put more "difficult" things closer to the top, because I know those are the things I will likely be fixing bugs in.